# Find all mapping from array/tuple to another array/tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get all mapping from input array to another array. Some thing like below ?

> a = ("a", "b", "c") b = ("d", "e")

#### Expected output

```
a-d
a-e
b-d
b-e
c-d
c-e
```

#### My current approach

```
a = ("a", "b", "c")
b = ("d", "e")

x = zip(a, b)
# [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e')]
```

#### Current solution

```
for i in a:
   for k in b:
      print(i, k)
```

Any Advance API or faster method than current approach in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`

I.e., `itertools.product(a, b)`

`itertools` is part of the standard library

#### Code Snippet

```
import itertools

a = ("a", "b", "c")
b = ("d", "e")

list(itertools.product(a, b))
```